# I need to make groups of 4-4-3 out of this shuffledClassroom list

Tags: c#, string, random, grouping, tstringlist

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> classroom = new List<string> { "Armen", "Babken", "Hayk", "Edgar", "Tatev", "Anna", "Aram", "Karo", "Baghdig", "Harut", "Ruzanna" };
    foreach (string student in classroom)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(student);
    }

    List<string> shuffledClassroom = ShuffleList(classroom);
    foreach (string student in shuffledClassroom)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(student);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}

static List<T> ShuffleList<T>(List<T> inputList)
{
    List<T> randomList = new List<T>();

    Random rnd = new Random();
    int randomIndex = 0;
    while (inputList.Count > 0)
    {
        randomIndex = rnd.Next(0, inputList.Count); 
        randomList.Add(inputList[randomIndex]);
        inputList.RemoveAt(randomIndex);
    }

    return randomList;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
List<string> classroom = new List<string> { "Armen", "Babken", "Hayk", "Edgar", "Tatev", "Anna", "Aram", "Karo", "Baghdig", "Harut", "Ruzanna" };
var groups = classroom.Select((x,i) => new {name = x, group = (int)i/4}).GroupBy(y => y.group).Select(z => z.Select(a => a.name).ToArray()).ToArray();
```

To get random list

```
List<string> classroom = new List<string> { "Armen", "Babken", "Hayk", "Edgar", "Tatev", "Anna", "Aram", "Karo", "Baghdig", "Harut", "Ruzanna" };
Random rand = new Random();
var groups = classroom.Select(m => new { name = m, rand = rand.Next()}).OrderBy(x => x.rand).Select((x,i) => new {name = x.name, group = (int)i/4}).GroupBy(y => y.group).Select(z => z.Select(a => a.name).ToArray()).ToArray();
```